# How to create button to addition every lines in DBGrid Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

how to make button on delphi 7 to execute addition with all data in dbgrid delphi.
for example 
i have database table with 3 coloumns show in dbgrid,

```
[CODE_NUMBER][ITEMS NAME][STOCK][NEW_STOCK]
 001          Rackets       1         5
 002          Sports Shoes  2         5
 003          Golf Hat      3         5 
 ... etc
```

How to create button when i click it, then dbgrid start addition

```
[STOCK] = [STOCK]+[NEW_STOCK]
```

after count in the first line, move to second line do the same addition
and so on until the end of the record in dbgrid and delete data in [NEW_STOCK] coloumn.
i've try with

```
if dbgrid1.fieldbyname('Code').value <> 0 then
begin
dbgrid1.fieldbyname('Stock').value := dbgrid1.fieldbyname('Stock').value + dbgrid1.fieldbyname('NEW_STOCK').value;
dbgrid1.next;
```

but only affect in the first line, nothing happen with the next lines in dbgrid

Comment: It is not 100% clear to me what you are trying to achieve, but i think perhaps what you need is a `calculated field`.  The calculated field is defined in the dataset and allows you to define the calculation in Delphi code.  Look at `OnCalcFields` in the help.

Comment: thanks for your attention David,

Comment: @Hugh Jones, Thanks for your attention, my problem is solved,

Answer (score 0):

To change data in dbgrid, you should use it's corresponding dataset, i.e.:

```
with dbgrid1.DataSource.DataSet do begin
  Edit;
  Fields.fieldbyname('Stock').value := Fields.fieldbyname('Stock').value + Fields.fieldbyname('NEW_STOCK').value;
  Post;
  Next;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

More efficient would be to do this at the database

The update statement to send to the database is very simple :

```
update yourtable set Stock = Stock + newStockValue where Code <> 0
```

and then just refresh your query or table component.